# Convert BufferedImage to ImageIcon

Tags: java, swing, bufferedimage, imageicon, image-conversion

How can I convert a BufferedImage to an ImageIcon?

I can not find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Use constructor: [`ImageIcon(Image image)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#ImageIcon%28java.awt.Image%29), `BufferedImage` extends `Image`.

Answer (score 24):

`BufferedImage` extends `Image`, so it's simply:

```
new ImageIcon(myBufferedImage);
```

Comment: Does the expression 'gone in 48 seconds' mean anything to you? ;)  +1 for your appearance anyway.

Answer (score 5):

```
File img = new File("C:\\..\\image.jpg");
BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(img);
ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(bufferedImage);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
your bufferimage;
JLabel photo = new JLabel("Photo");
photo.setIcon(new ImageIcon(bufferimage));
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple converter:

```
//Your icon
private ImageIcon icon;
//Your image
private BufferedImage image; 

 public void bufferImageTocon(){
     File file = new File("test.jpg");
     try {
         this.image = ImageIO.read(file);
     } catch (IOException ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
     } 

     icon = new ImageIcon(image); 
 }
```

Use just the constructor to make a new icon, setting the buffered image as a parameter.